# Why does boot.ini work with `partition(1)` but not with `partition(2)` when Windows is actually on partition 2?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mbr, ntldr, boot.ini

I have an MBR drive with a Windows XP installation on partition 2, which boots using a boot.ini entry that specifies `patition(2)`. The partition table initially looks like this:

```
1. Windows recovery partition
2. Windows XP
3. Linux
4. Linux
```

I then remove partition #1 and replace it with an extended partition, which results in this table:

```
1. Extended partition
2. Windows XP
3. Linux
4. Linux
```

Now Windows XP won't boot, complaining of a missing `hal.dll`. The partition number in boot.ini hasn't changed, and the partition number in the MBR partition table hasn't changed. Nevertheless, when I change Windows XP's boot entry in boot.ini from `partition(2)` to `partition(1)` Windows XP starts with no problems again. **I would like to know why, exactly.**

I'm reading https://neosmart.net/wiki/rebuilding-boot-ini-file/ which has this to say about boot.ini partition numbering:

> partition(y): The number of the partition on the drive rdisk(x).
> partition(y) starts counting from 1, so the first partition is
> partition(1), the second is partition(2), etc. partition(y) counts
> primary partitions first then counts logical partitions. The extended
> partition (the “container” for logical partitions) itself isn’t
> counted, though. **These numbers are taken from the Partition Table in
> the Master Boot Record**, which will generally be the order in which
> they were created, which will not necessarily be the same as the order
> in which they appear on the disk

Is this really true? Because from my perspective I seem to have changed the partition numbers simply by replacing partition entry 1 in the MBR.

For the record, `parted` tells me that the Windows XP partition is indeed number 2, and `fdisk` tells me it's `/dev/sda2` (though I'm not entirely prepared to trust device numbering schemes to correspond exactly to MBR partition numbers). Even if the operation of removing and replacing partition 1 did result in **rewriting the entire MBR partition table**, surely this output should confirm that the Windows partition did in fact end up in the right place anyway?

**Am I missing something in my understanding here?**

Comment: I have a horrible feeling that my answer lies in the quoted sentence **"The extended partition (the “container” for logical partitions) itself isn’t counted, though"**... I'll leave this an open opportunity for someone else to write an answer. I fell completely into that trap.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that your post contains all the elements for
understanding the answer, although there can be
more than one rule of counting that may apply
(as mentioned in your comment).

If the order of creation of the partition is the determinant in
allocating numbers, then the reason is that you had deleted partition #1,
therefore making #2 into the new #1.

The new Extended partition partition that you created is then following
all the other entries in its order of creation, so is presumable now
a higher number (perhaps #4 as it's now the last one).

To clarify, the quote you gave mentioned creation date, when
it probably really meant partition order. This would be the
same if deleted partition entries in the table are not reused
after deletion.

The partition-number allocation algorithm seems to be very
simple-minded :
Windows allocates partition numbers by their *order* in the
partition table, and not by their *position*.
So partition #1 may be found in table entry 2, if
entry number 1 is empty or a type that the BIOS will ignore
(I doubt that such types exist).

Comment: "If the order of creation of the partition is the determinant" That would imply that the MBR contains information on the order in which partition entries were created, keeping some sort of log of events. That's before taking into account that the MBR is likely written all at once when it's edited by tools like `fdisk`. Also, the quoted info on numbering does not say it uses creation order, but partition table numbering. I have to conclude it has nothing to do with the order of creation.

Comment: Your conclusion would be correct only if deleted entries were reused. If the new entry was added at the end of the partition table, instead of replacing the first one as you imply, then the creation order does matter. Perhaps a more precise formulation of the rule by Microsoft would have been better to say that the order of the partition table is determinant, rather than the physical layout of the partitions on the disk.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not only implying it since in the end of the Q I'm confirming which partition corresponds to which table item, using `parted`  At least I hope I'm doing that — I simply trusted another Q&A on that one, since `fdisk` did not seem to print table entry indices. Edit: seems like I did not report which partition ended up at index 1 which is a bit unclear, I grant you.

Comment: To clarify some more the rule in my answer : As I see it, Windows allocates partition numbers by their *order* in the partition table, and not by their *position*. So partition #1 may be found in table entry 2, if entry number 1 is empty or a type that the BIOS will ignore (I'm not sure that this exists).

Comment: That's about the same conclusion as I came to. My initial mistake was to assume that boot.ini used MBR indices and simply subtracted 1 from the logical partitions' indices, when in reality it seems to merely enumerate them in index order and skip some special cases (according to grawity's answer). At least one person seems to think it was too obvious to be worth asking about :) Well, maybe.

Comment: I also don't think it's obvious - many people had the same misconception and this post could help to dispel it. I added the above clarification to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind the entire "ARC path" facility in boot.ini is not native to BIOS/MBR systems. It comes from [ARC-type firmware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARC_(specification)) that was present on DEC Alpha systems – the original platform that Windows NT was built for, and the predecesor of today's EFI-type firmware – and the entirety of Windows' NTLDR (and boot.ini) is just an emulation of what would normally be provided by firmware on more advanced platforms.

Therefore, when the Windows bootloader interprets ARC paths on BIOS systems, it tries to hide MBR-specific quirks such as "extended partitions" and present a generic, flattened view of the *volumes* within (for lack of a better term). Since an extended partition doesn't directly represent something that would hold data, it is ignored here.

> I have a horrible feeling that my answer lies in the quoted sentence "The extended partition (the “container” for logical partitions) itself isn’t counted, though"...

Conveniently, the leaked source code of Windows XP is still available on Microsoft's GitHub. Digging through it, the partition number from the ARC path is ultimately handled by `HardDiskPartitionOpen()`, which has code to deliberately skip MBR partition slots from the count if they are either a) empty (type 0x00), b) EFI protective partition (0xEE), or c) `IsContainerPartition()` (0x05 or 0x0F). In other words, it does not count partition slots that have other purposes than directly holding data.

(Additionally, the position of the "extended" partition doesn't matter; it's always processed *after* the basic MBR slots have been processed.)

Comment: Interesting first paragraph. If I understand correctly Windows does not want any gaps in its partition numbering, and so it enumerates them itself, and the only role of the MBR entry indices is to determine in which order Windows assigns its partition numbers.